# Participation/participating and a couple more questions

Tags: word-usage

I'm helping my sister to prepare a cover letter for her job application and I have problems with a couple of sentences:

1) Something seems wrong in the sentence and I don't know what exactly:

> The participation in X international conferences and publishing X
>   articles in A1 scientific journals have dramatically improved my
>   presentation and writing skills.

2) Should we mention such a thing in the cover letter:

> I fully understand that the internship is probably not paid and it's acceptable to me.

3) Does it seem OK:

> I participated in a multidisciplinary research project collaborating with other scientific groups and learning how to

Thank you for your help in advance

Konstantin

Comment: 1) Please don't post multiple questions in a single post; 2) Your 2nd question is off topic, we deal with the language here not with what a cover letter should contain and 3) As is very clearly explained in the [Help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't like the first statement because it is passive and I hate passive writing. I especially dislike it when you are trying to be convincing, as in "hire me".

I would change:

> The participation in X international conferences and publishing X articles in A1     scientific journals have dramatically improved my presentation and writing skills.

to

> I have dramatically improved my presentation and writing skills by participating in X international conferences and publishing X articles in A1 scientific journals.

2) I fully understand that the internship is probably not paid and it's acceptable to me.

If you say this, it *will* be unpaid. It sounds like you are not confident in yourself and that they should only hire you because you come cheaper (or free).

3) I participated in a multidisciplinary research project collaborating with other scientific groups and learning how to

I don't like this. "multidisciplinary research project" kind of implies collaboration since researchers generally have an area of expertise.

Comment: When you say 'it is passive and I hate passive writing', do you mean to suggest that the passive voice is being used there? Because it isn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact linguistic construct is here. The OPs sentence is written "doing Y (participating) did X (improving writing) to me", but when creating resumes I like powerful sentences like "I did X (improved writing) by Y (attending conferences)".

Comment: Ah, what you are complaining about is [a failure to attribute agency](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3897)

Comment: By passive, I did not mean "passive voice", but passive in the sense of "lacking power or aggression". I prefer `I DID X`.